# my var i in for is stuck to it max value

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this code and i don't understant why my var i is equal to linksLen when i try to use it, can you explain to me please why?:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), 
linksLen = links.length;

for (var i = 0 ; i < linksLen ; i++) {

    links[i].addEventListener('keydown',function(e){

         if(document.getElementById('overlay').style.display =='block'){
             if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            alert(i);
            }
        }   


    });
}
```

};

Comment: Maybe you mean `mousedown` instead of `keydown`, since `keydown` refers to the keyboard?

See this fiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/5nkb4dqc/

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen: Why do you think Max means `mousedown`? What would a keyCode of 39 mean in such an event?

Comment: It's just that you don't usually type in Anchor elements. The element is not designed to capture the cursor like a form element. If you want to listen for a keycode, listen on the window or on an input element like `textarea`.


http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp

Comment: Also, you would properly want to assign the listener in a closed scope (as i do in the fiddle), so that `i` doesn't get overridden on each loop and you end up only having a reference to `i` at its peak size.